# Error in tmp.dat[, 2] : subscript out of bounds for epiR functions

Tags: r

It gives an error message

```
Error in tmp.dat[, 2] : subscript out of bounds
```

However I don't seem to have `tmp.dat`, could anyone help?

The code I use is the following:

```r
for (ii in 1:dim(mytable)[1]) {
  mytable[ii,c("X95.Low","X95.High")] <- (epiR::epi.conf(cbind(mytable[ii,"Yes"],mytable[ii,"No"]), ctype="prop.single")[c(3,4)])*100
}
```

[image: The image of mytable]

Comment: (1) Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block]. (2) Please don't spam tags; the [tag:rstudio] tag is reserved for questions about the RStudio IDE itself, not the R programming language. Stack's tag-recommendation is imperfect, please spend a moment to check tags it recommends for your questions.

Comment: https://github.com/cran/epiR/blob/87f5695fe769387c755b6b01a010801ced7b6903/R/epi.conf.R#L8

Comment: Does your data **have** a `"Yes"` column?  It's not apparent from the screenshot.

Comment: My guess, since we can't know with a partial image of data. One of: (1) you don't have a column named `"Yes"`, which will result in `NULL`; (2) you have a column named `"Yes"`, and if it's a base R `data.frame`, then `mytable[ii,"Yes"]` resolves to a scalar (single value), not two columns or more (which `epi.conf` needs internally in its `.propsingle()`); or (3) something else incomplete or missing in your data that we can't know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.